# Is it possible to update a value conditionally in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Suppose I'm storing records with the following structure in DynamoDB:

```
{
    "id": "574edeac445084d8d5aacc99b941d9d6",
    "status": "NEW",
    "blocked": false
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the following in one request?

If the record with the given id is blocked update status to BLOCKED or else to APPROVED

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. In a **single request**, you can include a [ConditionExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html#Expressions.ConditionExpressions.SimpleComparisons) that will either:

1. perform the update if the condition evaluates true *or*
2. abort the update if the condition evaluates false

For your implementation it seems like you would need support for some kind of `if ... else` *UpdateExpression* function, which according to the [list of comparison and function references for update expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html), is not available.

If this is **not an extremely frequent operation**, multiple requests would likely be fine. I can think of two options there:

1. Performa a GET request and then in your application compute the value you want to send in the UPDATE based on the response from the GET.
2. Attempt a "blind" UPDATE request with the ConditionExpression that you anticipate will yield the most success, and if it fails, compute the new value and send it with a second UPDATE request.

*For example: if you think that one condition expression will evaluate true 3/4's of the time, then you're only making two update requests 25% of the time. If you use the GET method above you're making a GET and an UPDATE 100% of the time. If there's a 50/50 chance that the first "blind" UPDATE attempt will fail, it might be easier to just use option number 1.*

If this **is an extremely popular operation**, you may want to rethink your table design. You might be able to [leverage sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html) to accomplish your goal.